# Slow Dataflow job draining

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a dataflow job that reads from pubsub subscription and writes to a Redis instance on a fixed time windows. The job seems to be running well with 4 workers and almost 0s systems latency until I try to drain it which causes upscaling to 10 workers and takes hours to finish.

I suspect this is caused by the windowing/grouping since the output collection metric suggest that it keeps producing elements long after the drain is started.

That's the windowing that I'm using.

```
beam.WindowInto(
         window.FixedWindows(size=120),
         trigger=Repeatedly(
             AfterAny(AfterCount(100), AfterProcessingTime(120))),
         accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING,
         allowed_lateness=Duration(seconds=2 * 24 * 60 * 60))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your large allowed lateness, when you drain your pipeline it causes every window for every key seen in the last 48 hours to close all at once, which is probably why there's so much work and it's upscaling. This could be especially bad if your keys are not often re-used.

Comment: Shouldn't the trigger send every "late" element for processing at most 120 seconds after that element arrived? Also given that the acumulation_mode is DISCARDING I don't get what the older message(the ones from the past 48 hours) are needed for.

Comment: The `allowed_lateness` parameter keeps these windows open for 48 hours, regardless of the trigger type. When the watermark advances (either over time, or suddenly due to a drain) these windows are officially closed and their results, if any, declared final.